# Converting GAP groups into SAGE permutation groups.

Tags: finite-groups, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath, computational-algebra, gap

I have been working with SAGE [online](http://www.sagemath.org/), and have made some programs to test some hypothesis about finite groups.  However, the pre-defined "named" groups in SAGE are quite limited (basically, the symmetric, dihedral, and alternating groups, plus PSL/PSU/PGUs and a couple sporadics).  SAGE evidently interfaces with GAP, so what I would like to do is pull some groups out of GAP's SmallGroups library so that I can run them through my SAGE code.

I am able to create a GAP group in SAGE with

```
A = gap.SmallGroup(27,4)
```

which returns

```
Group( [ f1, f2, f3 ] )
```

I can get its elements using

```
A.Elements()
```

which are then given to me in symbolic form, e.g.

```
[ <identity> of ..., f1, f2, f3, f1^2, f1*f2, f1*f3, f2^2, ... etc. ]
```

I just don't know how to turn these elements into permutations that SAGE can work with.  In other words, I want to take the gap.SmallGroup(27,4) and turn it into something of the form

```
Permutation Group with generators [(2,4,3), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3)]
```

Could anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: You might consider cross-posting this to Sage's dedicated stackoverflow-esque sage question site [asksage](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/).

Comment: Is it a stack-exchange faux pas to ask here how you got  gap.SmallGroup to run? I am having some difficulty with this - I have posted a question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366086/how-to-call-gaps-smallgroup-from-sage-i-am-getting-an-error-though-the-correc

Comment: Never mind, I resolved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now do this easily (i.e. without string processing) in Sage:

```
A = gap.SmallGroup(27,4)    
PermutationGroup(gap_group = A.AsPermGroup())
```

Comment: This raises
`RuntimeError: Gap produced error output
Error, Variable: 'AsPermGroup' must have a value`
for me. Has some syntax changed since this answer was posted 5 years ago?

Comment: This still seems to work for me, at least on Sage Cell Server: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzVLBVSE8s0AvOTczJcS_KLy3QMDLXMdFUAAKugNSi3NKSxJLM_DyIFFBlfDqIBdTlqOdYDFIAkdHUBABvWBgb&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Comment: Interesting, in my Jupyter notebook run from the Docker file sagemath/sagemath this does not work ...

`A = gap.Image(gap.IsomorphismPermGroup(gap.SmallGroup(27,4)))`
`PermutationGroup(gap_group = A)`

does, though.

Answer (score 5):

After a bit of inspection, gap groups have a function AsPermGroup built in. Which in your instance returns

```
Group( 
[ ( 1,10,19, 2,11,20, 3,12,21)( 4,14,24, 5,15,22, 6,13,23)( 7,18,26,
8,16,27,
      9,17,25), ( 1, 4, 7)( 2, 5, 8)( 3, 6,
9)(10,13,16)(11,14,17)(12,15,18)
    (19,22,25)(20,23,26)(21,24,27), ( 1, 2, 3)( 4, 5, 6)( 7, 8,
9)(10,11,12)
    (13,14,15)(16,17,18)(19,20,21)(22,23,24)(25,26,27) ] )
```

Presumably you could then pass this into a sage group. A simple hacky way to do this would be to turn the gap permutation group into a string, and remove the group and (). Although I would imagine that Gap has more functionality for groups than Sage does.

Comment: Better to turn not the group, but its individual generators - try `S:=Group((1,2),(1,2,3));; gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(S);; List(gens,String);` to see how it works. One can also use OpenMath package to have an output like e.g. `<OMOBJ> <OMA> <OMS cd="permut1" name="permutation"/> <OMI>2</OMI> <OMI>1</OMI> </OMA> </OMOBJ>` (see `OMString` from the OpenMath package).